# What should be the input-shape number when i am adding the input layer in my ANN, considering that I have preprocessed the data with OneHotEncoder?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

My dataset has categorical and numerical features. The dataset has 7 independent variables and 1 dependent variable (called as a product). The dataset looks like this:

[image]

In general, there are 3 categorical variables, where 7 different categories correspond to the variable p1, 2 for p2, and 2 for p3. From p4-p7 and product are numerical.

For the categorical variables (columns 0 , 1 and 2), it was necessary to preprocess the data by using OneHotEncoder.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct= ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0,1,2])], remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

From the result of that encoding, the number of columns has increased. That change we can see in the next image.

[image]

As we see, each category has its own code, and the number of columns has increased. Now I got '15 columns' (11 + 4) in the dataset.

So, when I construct the ANN, in the input layer, what value should I add in the input shape, 7 or 15?

ann.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(**??**,)))

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

After having run the fit line in my code, I have realized that the input-shape number must be equal to the number of columns obtained after the data preprocessing. Otherwise, it will result in an error.